# Class not found Error while integrating DynamicJasper with Struts 2.3.3

Tags: java, struts2, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I am using *DynamicJasper 4* and facing problem while integrating with *Struts 2.3.3*.

I've used the ***DynamicJasperStruts2-1.jar*** for displaying the generated report, but the problem is this jar imports ***`TextUtils`*** class which requires ***x-work 2.1*** library.

But for *Struts 2.3.3* we require ***xwork-core 2.3.3*** jar which does not contain the ***`TextUtils`*** class.

So while integrating I get the error `Class not found` so do update the ***DynamicJasperStruts2-1.jar*** so that its compatible with the *Struts 2.3.3*.

All my project are on *Struts 2.3*, so degrading down would be problem.

What can you recommend to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, download [latest version](http://archiva.fdvs.com.ar/repository/public1/ar/com/fdvs/DynamicJasper-Struts2/1.3/DynamicJasper-Struts2-1.3.jar) which resolves the issue:

or update your pom.xml to

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>ar.com.fdvs</groupId>
      <artifactId>DynamicJasper-Struts2</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

If i am correct `TextUtils` Utilities for common String manipulations, in fact this was ported from one of the opensymphony project.

Most of methods contained in the `TextUtils` was replaced in favor of apache commons and class was removed as it was no longer needed.

- [WW-3045](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3045)

My suggestion is to fix the issue with `DynamicJasperStruts2-1` as its using something which has been removed from the API in favor of more flexible and more elegant solution.

Else you will left no other choice than downgrading your S2 version which is not a recommend approach.

Comment: thats what i did buddy changed the DynamicJasperStruts2-1